# ADO.NET Data Services, LINQ

Tags: linq, service, ado.net

I have C# code to populate a dropdown list in Silverlight which works fine except when there are duplicates.  I think because `IEnumerable<Insurance.Claims>` is a collection, it filters out duplicates.  How would I code my LINQ query to accept duplicates?

My Sample Data looks like:

Code => CodeName
FGI      Field General Initiative
SRI      Static Resource Initiative
JFI      Joint Field Initiative - This is "overwritten" in results
JFI      Joint Friend Initiative

```
IEnumerable<Insurance.Claims> results;

// ADO.NET Data Service
var claim = (from c in DataEntities.Claims.Expand("Claimants").Expand("Policies")
             where c.Claim_Number == claimNumber
             select c);

DataServiceQuery<Insurance.Claims> dataServiceQuery =
    claim as DataServiceQuery<Insurance.Claims>;

dataServiceQuery.BeginExecute((asyncResult) =>
{
    results = dataServiceQuery.EndExecute(asyncResult);

    if (results == null)
    {
        // Error
    }
    else
    {
        // Code to populate Silverlight form
    }
});
```

Comment: IEnumerable is just an interface. It doesn't _do_ anything. In particular, it doesn't filter duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not sure if you're still struggling with this but anyway...)

I'm pretty sure it's not the IEnumerable interface but the actual drop down that is causing this behaviour. The code is being used as the key, and so obviously each time the same code is encountered, the item is being overwritten.

I don't think you can override this unless you change the code, or use another identifier as the key field in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add a try-catch block around `dataServiceQuery.EndExecute(asyncResult)` to properly handle errors.

Comment: This should be comment not an answer.